# Selenium Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I'm getting the out of memory exception when i put my ChromeDriver to headless mode.I haven't noticed it happening while ChromeDriver is working normally but when i put it in "headless" mode I'm getting exception.

The program is multi threaded and it should take the screenshot of captcha and convert it into base64.I've tried locking the method so only 1 thread can access but it's still happening.

```
 lock (this)
        {
            string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + ".png";
            Byte[] byteArray = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;
            Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray));
            Rectangle croppedImage = new Rectangle(element.Location.X, element.Location.Y, element.Size.Width, element.Size.Height);
            //EXCEPTION ON THE LINE BELOW
            screenshot = screenshot.Clone(croppedImage, screenshot.PixelFormat);
            screenshot.Save(String.Format(fileName, ImageFormat.Png));

            byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
            string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
            base64 = base64ImageRepresentation;
            File.Delete(fileName);
        }
```

Comment: You don't dispose your resources properly. Particularly, `MemoryStream` and `Bitmap` classes are `IDisposable` and you need to dispose them by wrapping into `using ()` statements to optimize usage of memory.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: There can be another reason of this behaviour though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318563/c-sharp-out-of-memory-when-creating-bitmap. But you still need to dispose the resources properly.

Comment: Sure, here is the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects

Comment: I've wrapped them both but i'm still getting out of memory exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199468/c-sharp-image-clone-out-of-memory-exception